# До какого условия выполняется цикл

Tags: javascript

У меня есть функция, которая значения из списка превращает в массив. Я не понимаю до какого условия работает node в цикле, объясните пожалуйста.

```js
function listToArray(list) {
  let array = [];
  for (let node = list; node; node = node.rest) {
    array.push(node.value);
  }
  return array;
}
```

Comment: А так `for (let node = list; node != null; node = node.rest)` Вам понятнее?

Comment: А rest соответственно указывает на следующий элемент списка. Т.е. цикл работает, пока у вас есть следующий элемент.

Comment: Цикл работает пока значение `node` истинно... то есть, до условия `Boolean(node) === false`.

Comment: Проверка условия (вычисление второго выражения `for`) выполняется после каждой итерации, и выполнения третьего выражения оператора (`node = node.rest`).